# Python: calling function inside if statement from another File

Tags: python, function, if-statement, module

I have an error in my program: "Taula_G3110 ()
`NameError: name 'Taula_G3110' is not defined"`

My question is:
I want to call a function that is inside an IF loop.This function is in another file. I have tried everything with imports:
`"from Kleben_Tabelle import Taula_G3110, Taula_G3111`.
`import Kleben_Tabelle` ", but there is no way.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
#from Kleben_Tabelle import *
import serial
import time
import PIL.Image
import Kleben_Tabelle


root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x600")
# root.resizable (False,False)
root.title("Combobox")

arduino = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600)
time.sleep(0.1)  # reducir el uso de la CPU.Prueba con diferentes valores (0.01 a 0.1)


def cambiar():
    mes = combo.get()
    if mes == "G3110":
        label_resultat.configure(text=txt)
        Taula_G3110()

    if mes == "G3111":
        label_resultat.configure(text=txt2)
        Taula_G3111()
    if mes == "G3112":
        messagebox.showinfo("Mes", "Marzo")

def apagarLED():
    arduino.write(b'4')
    time.sleep(1)


def cerrarInterfaz():
    # cerrar comunicación Serial
    global raiz
    arduino.close()
    # cerrar ventana
    root.destroy()

image = Image.open ('Edifici_Knauer_blau.png')
photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = Label(root, image=photo_image)
label.pack()

frame_resultat = Frame(root, width=400, height=100, relief="flat", highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=1)
frame_resultat.place(x=250, y=200)

label_resultat = Label(root, text="", bg="yellow", borderwidth=0, relief="groove", width=20, height=2, justify='left',
                       highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=1)
label_resultat.place(x=80, y=200)

etiqueta = Label(root, text="Zelle: Kleben")
etiqueta.place(x=100, y=40)

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, state="readonly")
combo.place(x=100, y=70)
combo["values"] = ("G3110", "G3111", "G3112", "1")
combo.current(0)

boton = Button(root, text="Cambiar mes", command=cambiar)
boton.place(x=100, y=100)

# boton de apagado del LED
btnApagar = ttk.Button(root, text="Reset", command=apagarLED)
# btnApagar = ttk.Button(raiz,text ="Reset",command = clearTextInput)
btnApagar.place(x=420, y=450)
# boton de Cerrar interfaz
btnCerrar = ttk.Button(root, text="Cerrar", command=cerrarInterfaz)
btnCerrar.place(x=420, y=480)

txt = ("G3110 Frontabdeckung")
txt2 = ("G3111 Frontabdeckung")

root.mainloop()
```

---

and this ist my other File with this Module-Function:(File: Kleben_Tabelle.py)

```
def Taula_G3110():
    arduino.write(bytes(b'T'))
    arbol = ttk.Treeview(frame_resultat,columns=("Bauteile","Regal","Lager"))
    arbol.column ('#0',width=100)
    arbol.column ('Bauteile',width=100)
    arbol.column ('Regal',width=80)
    arbol.column ('Lager',width=80)
    arbol.insert("",END,text="G3110",values=("P6400","K2.0001.01","Regal 2"))
    arbol.insert("",END,text="G3110",values=("P6406XA","K1.0004.01"))
    arbol.insert("",END,text="G3110",values=("P6403XA","K1.0003.01"))
    arbol.heading("#0",text="Model")
    arbol.heading("Bauteile",text="Bauteile")
    arbol.heading("Regal",text="Regal")
    arbol.place(x=100,y=70)
    arbol.pack()
```

Comment: you're probably best off posting the actual code, and adding a tag for the programming language you're using. May I suggest: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your import looks correct, assuming it is a function in that module. Maybe post the exception stack trace from the import statement? What do you mean "inside an if statement"? If you can post code to recreate the error here, we can certainly help.

Comment: Thanks Kenn Ostrom

Comment: In the example above, you should be using `Kleben_Tabelle.Taula_G3110()` when calling the function. I assume you've tried that though. Other than that - we need to know the disk layout of your project and possibly your PYTHONPATH value. We also need to see the code in the Kleben_Tabelle module.

Comment: I call the function as you told me...no error 
but now I get this error: arduino.write(bytes(b'T'))
NameError: name 'arduino' is not defined

Comment: and my Pythonpath.(sorry,I am not sure if what I have done is correct):
C:\Program Files\Python310\python310.zip
C:\Program Files\Python310\DLLs
C:\Program Files\Python310\lib
C:\Program Files\Python310
C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages
C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyserial-3.5-py3.10.egg
>>>

Comment: OK, so the answer here is that you're not referencing the Taula_G3110 function correctly. In the other script it looks like you're not importing the arduino module at all. Do you have an `import arduino` statement?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a function in a module that you've imported, you need to reference the module and function like so:

```py
import Kleben_Tabelle

...

def cambiar():
    mes = combo.get()
    if mes == "G3110":
        label_resultat.configure(text=txt)
        Kleben_Tabelle.Taula_G3110()
```

Comment: the import of the module, I have also made it
The import of the Serial library for arduino also: 
import serial
But I still have the error: arduino.write(bytes(b'T'))
NameError: name 'arduino' is not defined

Comment: Hi @KamaeBerlin that sounds like a different question to this. Please either update this question with the other module's contents to show us what you're doing or else post a new question with all that information in and we can help with that question. Unfortunately there's never enough information in a comment to be able to hazard a guess at a solution.

Comment: I have asked another question. I hope this makes it clearer. Thank you very much anyway.:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70867361/python-calling-function-module-inside-if-statement-from-another-file